# Discord.py make bot send a message to specific channel on keypress

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a program that would run a discord bot and make it so whenever I press the right arrow key - the bot would send a message to a specific channel, but I get an error and I don't know how to do this.

```py
import discord, os, pyperclip
from pynput import keyboard

client = discord.Client()
with open('token.txt', 'r') as f:
    token = f.readline()


def on_press(key):
    if key == keyboard.Key.right:
        myChannel = client.get_channel(763382459504132136)
        myChannel.send("sent to specific channel")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"Logged in as {client.user}")

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    client.run(token)
listener.join()
```

Here is what pops up in my terminal:

Logged in as Baku#8196
C:\Users\Venyl\Desktop\VS CODE\Code 2020\discordbot\discordbot.py:12: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited   myChannel.send("sent to specific channel")
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback

Comment: you are missing a bunch of `async` and `await` statements

Comment: I'm not that good at programming and I'm new to discord.py, can you elaborate?

Comment: Sending a channel is a asynchronious operation (as in, it will not complete immediately but rather at some unknown time in the future. Typically you `await` such statements, or use `asyncio.create_task` to run it in the background

Comment: When I add async before `def on_press` and await before `myChannel.send` I get the same error but with 'on_press' instead of 'Messageable.send' and there's no "myChannel.send("sent to specific channel")"

Comment: Looks like whatever keyboard library you use doesn't like async code. You can use `asyncio.create_task` though be sure to store the task since it will be cancelled if garbage collected

Comment: I've been trying to do that and I don't know how

Comment: @Venyl I suggest you read up on how [coroutines in python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html) works before you tackle on this issue. discord.py is not a beginner-friendly library, so you will have to do some reading on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my part of code from `myChannel.send("sent to specific channel")` to `client.loop.create_task(myChannel.send('sent to specific channel'))` and it works.